# If I close the laptop lid the next boot fails

Tags: laptop, hibernate

I never shutdown my laptop. I use hibernate instead. Hibernate and suspend are working, but if I close the lid after clicking "Hibernate" the next boot will crash. I see a black screen that never goes away and I have to hard reset it holding the power button losing all my open applications.

I hate when I forget it and I close the lid! Is there a solution for this? Is this a compatibility problem with no solution?

My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad Y460 running Debian wheezy.

Linux 2.6.39-2-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 5 02:51:22 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I've seen this too. I think what happens is your suspend function kicks in on top of the already in-progress hibernate. When the system tries to come back on it's a tangled mess. I just make sure the hibernate function is finished and the system is off before I close my lid IF I have anything running that makes it sleep on the lid closed (I only sometimes run a power daemon that does that.)

Comment: If Caleb is correct, A solution would be to find the hibernate and sleep scripts and perform and add a mutex to the top. Add a pid file to /var/run and check for it before actually executing anything.

Comment: If you need help doing that let me know, but I am not sure where scripts are in general and I don't have a debian computer to find out.

Comment: pm-XX functions have locks so suspend and hibernate won't come together

Answer (score 1):

In your Power features setup, there's an option for 'action when closing lid'... change that from 'suspend' to 'none', or even to 'hibernate'.  If you set it to hibernate, then you don't have to click anything... just close the lid, and it'll hibernate automatically.

If you're running KDE, it's:

- system settings
- Power Management (light bulb, towards bottom)
- Energy Saving Settings (Top item on left column)
- Button Events Handling (second from bottom, right side).
- "When Laptop Lid Closed..." setting.

There's three tabs (top, right side) which determine actions for AC, Battery and Low Battery states.